# How to use the same form present in HTML to appear on different places in a page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, css

I'm trying to create a comment stream just like on Reddit using HTML/jQuery.

I already have the comment form for main post reply button working just like the way I want and now I'm looking to use that same form for all the child comments reply button.

I tried to do it with below jQuery code using inserAfter() but it worked only partially i.e When I'm clicking on reply button of any child comment the comment form is appearing once for the last child comment and then when I'm clicking it twice comment form is getting displayed for all the child comments.

Below is my jQuery -

```
$(".comment-box-link, .comment-box").on('click', function(e) {
    $('.new-topic-wrapper').slideToggle('fast');

    if ($(".new-topic-wrapper").is(':visible')) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".new-topic-wrapper").offset().top - 50 }, 'fast');
    }
});
$('.comment-box').click(function(e) {
    $('.new-topic-wrapper').show().insertAfter('.comment-bottom');
});
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle or Plunker ?

Comment: Added codepen link

Comment: Some HTML for context would be helpful, a [MCVE] would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the function to attach to the `single-comment-wrapper` clicked. Find the appropriate ancestor of the clicked button, then attach after the desired element:

```
$('.comment-box').click(function(e) {
    $('.new-topic-wrapper').show().insertAfter($(this).closest('.single-comment-wrapper').find('.comment-bottom'));
});
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/broyzo

Answer (score 0):

You can load your page html content in a div via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'html_file.html',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',

})
.done(function(result) {
    $("#output").html(result);
});
```

> Try using ajax for loading html in your page - **[Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**